# Can not convert typedef to std::pair in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, stl

I try to upgrade some projects from `Visual Studio 2010` to `2015`. In `2010` everything works fine, but in `2015` I get compiler errors which I don't really understand.

I condensed the code into an SSCCE

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

#define UNUSED(x) (void(x))

class ColumnDef
{
public:
};

class XMLColumnDef
{
public:
    typedef std::pair<std::string, XMLColumnDef> pair;
    typedef std::pair<std::string, XMLColumnDef *> ptr_pair;

public:
    // Move constructor for moving the column into an container
    // without destroying it. Note that the source is no longer valid after 
    // such a move.
    XMLColumnDef(XMLColumnDef &oSource)
    {
        mColumn = oSource.mColumn;
        oSource.mColumn = NULL;
    }

    XMLColumnDef(ColumnDef *pColumn)
    {
        mColumn = pColumn;
    }

    virtual ~XMLColumnDef(void)
    {
        delete mColumn;
    }

private:
    ColumnDef *mColumn;
};

class XMLNodeObserver
{
public:
    typedef std::map<std::string, XMLNodeObserver *> map;
    typedef std::pair<std::string, XMLNodeObserver *> pair;
    typedef std::map<std::string, XMLColumnDef> row_def;

public:
    XMLNodeObserver(void) {}
    virtual ~XMLNodeObserver(void) {};

    void addObserver(XMLNodeObserver::map &oNodeObserver, std::string const &oPath, XMLNodeObserver *oObserver = NULL)
    {
        UNUSED(oNodeObserver);
        UNUSED(oPath);
        UNUSED(oObserver);
    }
    void addColumnDef(XMLNodeObserver::map &oNodeObserver, std::string const &oPath, ColumnDef *oColumn, XMLNodeObserver *oObserver = NULL)
    {
        if (oObserver == NULL)
            oObserver = this;

        addObserver(oNodeObserver, oPath, oObserver);

        XMLColumnDef::pair pr = std::make_pair(oPath, XMLColumnDef(oColumn));

        if (oObserver->mColumnDefs.find(oPath) != oObserver->mColumnDefs.end())
        {
            // If a node already exists, we report an internal error, because this indicates a program bug and should be fixed.
            std::cerr << "INTERNAL ERROR: Duplicate rowdef key in XML node observer: " << oPath << std::endl;
        }
        oObserver->mColumnDefs.insert(pr);
    }

private:
    row_def mColumnDefs;
    bool mDebugMode;
};

int main()
{
    XMLNodeObserver o;
    XMLNodeObserver::map om;

    o.addColumnDef(om, "/testpath", new ColumnDef());

    std::cout << "\nDone! Press any key..." << std::endl;
    std::cin.ignore();

    return 0;
}
```

The error I get in this line:

```
oObserver->mColumnDefs.insert(pr);
```

The error I get is this:

```
junk.cpp(104): error C2664: 'void std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>::insert(std::initializer_list<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'XMLColumnDef::pair' to 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty> &&'
          with
          [
              _Kty=std::string,
              _Ty=XMLColumnDef,
              _Pr=std::less<std::string>,
              _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,XMLColumnDef>>
          ]
          and
          [
              _Kty=std::string,
              _Ty=XMLColumnDef
          ]
junk.cpp(104): note: Reason: cannot convert from 'XMLColumnDef::pair' to 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>'
          with
          [
              _Kty=std::string,
              _Ty=XMLColumnDef
          ]
junk.cpp(104): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

It looks as if `Visual Studio 2015` doesn't like it that the parameter `oPath` is `const &` but that shouldn't matter as it should be assigned to the `pair` member.

I also removed the `typedefs` and tried to compile it with the long names, but that doesn't seem to be the problem (and shouldn't anyway) because I get the same error.

Like:

```
std::pair<std::string, XMLColumnDef> pr = std::pair<std::string, XMLColumnDef>(oPath, XMLColumnDef(oColumn));
```

Comment: A SSCCE which requires 9 different headers?! This isn't the smallest example which demonstrates the problem. For instance, you'd have a **massive** simplification by replacing your map value type `XMLColumnDef>` with just `int`, and you'd still have the same error (which is a `const Key` problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pairs in maps are of type `pair<const key,value>` and not `pair<key,value>`. Try using the `MyMapType::value_type` typedef instead. You get it for free!

example:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, XMLNodeObserver *> MyMapType;
typedef MyMapType::value_type MyPairType;
```

Comment: That fixed the compile error but now I get a new one : `error C2558: class 'XMLColumnDef': no copy constructor available or copy constructor is declared 'explicit'`. But I can't add a copy constructor, because the pointer should be moved.

Comment: so replace `ColumnDef*` member with `shared_ptr<ColumnDef>`. Then you won't have to copy the data, just share the pointer.

Comment: And who will release it when the Node is no longer used? That's why I put in the move idiom.

Comment: shared_ptr will delete the ColumnDef* object when the last copy of XMLColumnDef is destructed. It's exactly what you need right now ;)

Comment: @Devolus: Check which method gives you that error. Chances are, you're using the wrong map method. Are you using `emplace` ?

Comment: @MSalters, I was using insert, but it already works with the shared pointer.